# Validating text fields completeness with logical conditions

Tags: java, validation, events, javafx, javafx-8

I'm coding a JavaFX App, I have 6 **`TextFields`**  which are required fields. I also have a default button which is innactive at first.

I want to use logic to check wether all fields have been filled. I have a variable `estado` initiated `false`.

Coded:

```
    if (!((TextField)event.getSource()).getText().trim().isEmpty())
        estado = estado | true;
    else 
        estado = false;

    if (estado)
        button.setDisabled(false)
```

All `TextFields` got that method after a `KeyReleased` event.

I've got not good results fo far.

Comment: You probably don't want to rely on key events (for example, the user might use the mouse to copy-nad-paste). Observe the textProperty() of the text fields for changes instead.

Answer (score 1):

This for basic solution if you need more plz tell...

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package textfieldlogic;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author reegan
 */
public class TextFieldLogic extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FormattedTextField btn = new FormattedTextField("^[1-9]+$");
        btn.setText("Only Enter Numbers");

        FormattedTextField btn1 = new FormattedTextField("^[a-z]+$");
        btn1.setText("Only Enter Characters");

        VBox vBox = new VBox(20);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(btn,btn1);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public class FormattedTextField extends TextField {

    Matcher matcher;

    public FormattedTextField(String regex) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        matcher = pattern.matcher("");
        EventHandler<KeyEvent> filter = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                String s = getText() + t.getCharacter();
                matcher.reset(s);
                if (!( matcher.matches() || matcher.hitEnd())) {
                    t.consume();
                }
            }
        };
        addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, filter);
    } 
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if [this gist](https://gist.github.com/james-d/9904574) helps. The validation work is done in the Controller file. This is a bit more extensive than your question, but might give you some ideas.

Instead of listening for events (or changes in properties), I bind the disableProperty to various `BooleanBinding`s. These `BooleanBinding`s encapsulate the notion of "valid/invalid" for a given control or set of controls.

For a simple version of this, for your example, you could do something like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SimpleTextFieldValidation extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField tf1 = new TextField();
        TextField tf2 = new TextField();
        TextField tf3 = new TextField();
        TextField tf4 = new TextField();
        TextField tf5 = new TextField();
        TextField tf6 = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("Submit");

        button.disableProperty().bind(
            emptyTextFieldBinding(tf1)
                .or(emptyTextFieldBinding(tf2))
                .or(emptyTextFieldBinding(tf3))
                .or(emptyTextFieldBinding(tf4))
                .or(emptyTextFieldBinding(tf5))
                .or(emptyTextFieldBinding(tf6))
             );

        VBox root = new VBox(5, tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5, tf6, button);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 150, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private BooleanBinding emptyTextFieldBinding(TextField textField) {
        return Bindings.length(textField.textProperty()).isEqualTo(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```